# Will the roots of $p(p(x))=0$ be purely real or purely imaginary or neither?

Tags: functions, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots, real-numbers

**Question**

The quadratic equation $p(x)=0$ with real coefficients has purely imaginary roots. Then the equation $p(p(x))=0$ will have -

a) only purely imaginary roots

b) all real roots

c) two real and two imaginary roots

d) neither real nor purely imaginary roots

**My Thoughts**

I assumed a quadratic equation $${p(x)=ax^2+bx+c=0}$$ Now, as the coefficients are real the two roots must be conjugates. Let these roots be $ki$ and $-ki$.
Satisfying it in the equation gives $b=0 \Rightarrow p(x)=ax^2+c=0$ or $x^2+λ=0$ where $λ=c/a$ (to reduce the variables).
Now, putting it in $p(p(x))=0$ we get $x^4+2λx^2+λ^2+λ=0$. Now I am stuck here. I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: Hint: If $p(p(x))=0$, then $p(x)$ is a root of $p$.

Comment: You have expanded $\frac{1}{a} p\left( \frac{1}{a} p(x) \right)$, but this is not equal to $p(p(x))$ or a multiple of it, and will have different roots.

Comment: What happens if you make $x$ purely imaginary in $ax^2+c$? Can the result be a root of $p(x)$?

Comment: Have you thought about using the formulas for roots of quadratic polynomials?

Comment: @aschepler Sorry, yes you are right. I should have kept a and c separate and after opening p(p(x)) should have reduced variable.

Comment: @aschepler Then I would get p(p(x))= a^3x^4+2ca^2x^2+ac^2+c=0.

Comment: By applying quadratic formula I am getting $${x^2= -c/a ± root(c/a)i}$$

Comment: What do I interpret from this?

Answer (score 1):

WLOG the polynomial has the form $p(x)=x^2+a^2$. Then

$$(x^2+a^2)^2+a^2=0$$ has two distinct pairs of complex conjugate roots.

Comment: So, the answer should be (d) right? Can you also confirm whether $${x^2=-c/a±root(c/a)i)}$$ should be the general solution?

Comment: For $${a(ax^2+c)^2+c=0}$$

Comment: @InfiniteCool23: no, redo the resolution.

Comment: Sorry, is it $${x^2=-c/a±(1/a)root(c/a) i}$$